# Repeatedly Complementary subsets

Tags: r

I want to repeatedly divide a set into two complementary subsets with known size and keep them as the columns of two matrix. For example assume the main set is {1, 2, ..., 10}, the size of first sample is 8 and I want to repeat sampling 3 times. I want to have:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10    9    1
[2,]    8    1   10
[3,]    3    7    5
[4,]    4    2    3
[5,]    1    8    8
[6,]    6    4    2
[7,]    9    5    7
[8,]    5   10    6
```

and

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    7    6    9
```

Any idea how to implement it in R avoiding `for` loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `replicate` + `sample`, like this:

```
set.seed(1)                             # Just so you can replicate my results
A <- replicate(3, sample(10, 8, FALSE)) # Change 3 to the number of replications
A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    7    8
# [2,]    4    1    9
# [3,]    5    2    4
# [4,]    7    8    6
# [5,]    2    5    7
# [6,]    8   10    2
# [7,]    9    4    3
# [8,]    6    6    1
```

For the other set, I would use `apply` + `setdiff`, like this:

```
B <- apply(A, 2, function(x) setdiff(1:10, x))
B
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    5
# [2,]   10    9   10
```

---

Another option as suggested by @thelatemail (which would be more efficient) is to just create use `replicate` to create your original matrix, and use basic subsetting to create your separate matrices.

```
A <- replicate(3, sample(10))
B <- A[-(seq_len(8)), ]
A <- A[seq_len(8), ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know how to implement apply

Comment: A variation on a theme: `A <- replicate(3,sample(10));B <- A[-(seq_len(8)),];A <- A[seq_len(8),];`

Comment: @thelatemail, that would be more efficient than `apply`--I've edited it into the answer.